# Initializing or assigning struct members of variable array directly, with reference to named struct members, in C?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, initialization, variable-assignment

In similar questions on SO and elsewhere, the only solution in this case that is talked about is to initialize the array of structs with array notation, not using dot-names of the struct members. The closest I have got to what I want is with the following code:

```
int texturesCount = 2;
struct textureParams textures[texturesCount];
struct textureParams textures0 =   {
                                        .textureFormat = textureFormat,
                                        .textureAccess = textureAccess,
                                        .srcrect = {.x = 0, .y = 0, .w = 50, .h = 50},
                                        .dstrect = {.x = 0, .y = 500, .w = 50, .h = 50},
                                        .r = 255,
                                        .g = 0,
                                        .b = 0,
                                        .a = 0,
                                    };
struct textureParams textures1 =   {
                                        .textureFormat = textureFormat,
                                        .textureAccess = textureAccess,
                                        .srcrect = {.x = 0, .y = 0, .w = 20, .h = 20},
                                        .dstrect = {.x = 10, .y = 100, .w = 20, .h = 20},
                                        .r = 0,
                                        .g = 255,
                                        .b = 0,
                                        .a = 0,
                                    };
textures[0] = textures0;
textures[1] = textures1;
```

Is there a way of doing this - creating the struct members of the array with reference to the named struct members - but without creating the temporary variables `texture0` and `texture1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to for example create an array of `int` you could initialize it like this:

```
int arr[3] = { 3, 4, 5 };
```

It's the same in your case except it's an array of structs, and each initializer is a struct initializer:

```
struct textureParams textures[texturesCount] = {
    {
        .textureFormat = textureFormat,
        .textureAccess = textureAccess,
        .srcrect = {.x = 0, .y = 0, .w = 50, .h = 50},
        .dstrect = {.x = 0, .y = 500, .w = 50, .h = 50},
        .r = 255,
        .g = 0,
        .b = 0,
        .a = 0,
    },
    {
        .textureFormat = textureFormat,
        .textureAccess = textureAccess,
        .srcrect = {.x = 0, .y = 0, .w = 20, .h = 20},
        .dstrect = {.x = 10, .y = 100, .w = 20, .h = 20},
        .r = 0,
        .g = 255,
        .b = 0,
        .a = 0,
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but GCC throws "error: variable-sized object may not be initialized    struct textureParams textures[texturesCount] = { "

Comment: @Theod'Or You'll need to make the array size a compile time constant.  You can do that by changing `texturesCount` to a `#define` macro instead of a variable.

Comment: @Theod'Or A variable length array (regardless of type) cannot be initialized at all because its size is not known at compile time.

Comment: Doh! I just realized that it doesn't have to be variable - that looks obvious now from the code. Answer accepted, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can directly assign to array's members using compound literals:

```
    int texturesCount = 2;
    struct textureParams textures[texturesCount];

    textures[0] = (struct textureParams) {
            .textureFormat = textureFormat,
            .textureAccess = textureAccess,
            .srcrect = {.x = 0, .y = 0, .w = 50, .h = 50},
            .dstrect = {.x = 0, .y = 500, .w = 50, .h = 50},
            .r = 255,
            .g = 0,
            .b = 0,
            .a = 0,
    };
    textures[1] = (struct textureParams) {
            .textureFormat = textureFormat,
            .textureAccess = textureAccess,
            .srcrect = {.x = 0, .y = 0, .w = 20, .h = 20},
            .dstrect = {.x = 0, .y = 100, .w = 20, .h = 20},
            .r = 0,
            .g = 255,
            .b = 0,
            .a = 0,
    };
```

Comment: Is the casting to `(struct textureParams)` really necessary?

Comment: @MiCo It has resemblance to casting but is not a casting. It is called _compound literal_. It provides an unnamed object. Cast operator does not provide an object. And yes, it is necessary to designate a `struct` literal. Note that it is not an initialization but an assignment.

Comment: Wow, learn something new every day! If I hadn't realized that the array did not need to be variable, this would have been the answer I was looking for. I'm a fan of the old K&R2 book, which only talks about "compound statements". Are "compound literals" the same thing or a later invention?

Comment: @Theod'Or Compound literals are introduced by the C99 standard. So, yes, a later invention.

Comment: @LxerLx: Thank you very much for that hint. I did not know before about these "compound literals" and I tried them out successfully. And yes: without the designator it does not compile.